# A question related to the union-closed sets conjecture

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Let $f(n)$ denote the maximum possible cardinality of a collection $\mathcal F$ of nonempty sets which is closed under unions ($X,Y\in\mathcal F\implies X\cup Y\in\mathcal F$) and is such that no element belongs to more than $n$ members of $\mathcal F$.

It follows from [the union-closed sets conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-closed_sets_conjecture) that $f(n)\le2n-1$. (That's $2n-1$ instead of $2n$ because I'm omitting the empty set, which seems irrelevant to me.)

However, the upper bound $2n-1$ does not seem to be the best possible in all cases. I may have figured these things wrong, but it seems to me that $f(3)=4$ and $f(5)=8$ and $f(6)=9$. (Of course $f(n)\ge2n-1$ if $n=2^k$.)

**Question.** Is there a conjectured exact value for $f(n)$?